# Convert output of ndgrid to a single array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I want to create an n-dimensional grid from vectors xi which specify the desired grid points in dimension i. The output should be a single N x n matrix, where N=b1*b2*b3*...*bn is the total number of grid points, and bi is the number of desired grid points along that dimension. (I want to do this in Matlab.)

I know that I can use the `ndgrid` function to create this n-dimensional grid, but `ndgrid` returns n cell arrays, each of dimension b1xb2xb3x...xbn. How can I transform this to a single array, as desired?

An additional complication: I do not know the dimension n in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David already got the idea in his comment, just a minor error for n>=4.

```
function grid_array = ndgridarr(n, varargin)

    assert(length(varargin) == 1 || length(varargin) == n);

    grid_cells = cell(1, n);
    [grid_cells{:}] = ndgrid(varargin{:});

    grid_array = reshape(cat(n+1,grid_cells{:}),[],n);
end
```

An alternative is to use `allcomb` from [file exchange](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb-varargin) or 
`combvec` (Deep learning toolbox). They both already return a single matrix, no need to stich the cell array together.

Comment: Nitpick: no need for the `+1` in the `cat` dimension. Yes, that makes the intervening array more nicely structured, but since it gets `reshape`d right away anyway it's sufficient for the arrays to be concatenated on the highest *existing* dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution. I'd be *very* happy to hear about simpler approaches.

```
function grid_array = ndgridarr(n, varargin)

    assert(length(varargin) == 1 || length(varargin) == n);

    grid_cells = cell(1, n);
    [grid_cells{:}] = ndgrid(varargin{:});

    grid_array = cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) c(:), grid_cells, 'UniformOutput', false));
end
```

You can call this function exactly like you would `ndgrid`, just with the additional input parameter n. (`ngrid` infers n automatically from the number of output arguments in the case when just a single vector is provided, but we cannot do this since we have only one output parameter in any case.)

Two examples illustrating that it does what's desired:

```
>> ndgridarr(3, [1,2,3])

ans =

     1     1     1
     2     1     1
     3     1     1
     1     2     1
     2     2     1
     3     2     1
     1     3     1
     2     3     1
     3     3     1
     1     1     2
     2     1     2
     3     1     2
     1     2     2
     2     2     2
     3     2     2
     1     3     2
     2     3     2
     3     3     2
     1     1     3
     2     1     3
     3     1     3
     1     2     3
     2     2     3
     3     2     3
     1     3     3
     2     3     3
     3     3     3

>> ndgridarr(3, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6])

ans =

     1     3     5
     2     3     5
     1     4     5
     2     4     5
     1     3     6
     2     3     6
     1     4     6
     2     4     6
```

Comment: Once you have `grid_cells` you can do `grid_array = reshape(cat(3,grid_cells{:}),[],n)` instead.